# Python 2.7+: What's the correct way to format a float in non-scientific notation with certain precision?

Tags: python, floating-point

I hope I am making sense with this question.

Sometimes if I print a small float it'll look like `6.1248979238e-05` or something similar.

I want to be able to say "No matter what, output 10 digits precision like so": `0.abcdefghij`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> '%0.10f'% 6.1248979238e-05 
'0.0000612490'
```

This is "string interpolation" or [printf-style formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) which is still widely supported and used.  Another option is the [newer style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(6.1248979238e-05)
'0.0000612490'
```

Or if you want to be python2.6 compatible:

```
>>> '{0:.10f}'.format(6.1248979238e-05)
'0.0000612490'
```

Take your pick.  Which version you use depends on which versions of python you want to support.  If you're targeting *only* python2.7, it doesn't matter.  If you want to support earlier versions use printf-style.  I've personally switched to using the last form in *most* of my code.  I don't care about python2.5 support, but python2.6 is still new enough that I'd like to support it where possible.

Comment: I looked into this method too but it seemed like it was outdated syntax or something like that -- is this the "correct" way to do it?

Comment: % formatting is technically depreciated ... but will still be around for a while ... "{}" formatting is the new style that will replace % formatting ... but it has been around since python2.5(?) maybe before that...

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- `.format` was introduced in python2.6. I believe `%` formatting was at one point marked as deprecated, but I believe that has been un-deprecated due to pushback from the community (which is actually why I linked to the python3.3 documentation instead of the 2.7 docs :-)

Comment: oh nice I didnt know it had become undepreciated ... tbh I prefer the % formatting ... thanks for the info!

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- I think that those who learned C first often use % formatting more (that's why it's still my first instinct).  That said, `.format` can do some pretty nifty stuff...

Comment: @mgilson lol that comment mirrored the conversation i just had with my coworker

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- :extrapolating: then your coworker must be one handsome fellow!